# Where customize prompt for all existing and new users?

Tags: ubuntu, users, prompt

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
To customize the prompt of an user I know that I have to edit `~/.bashrc`. But to override the `~/.bashrc` of all existing users which file should I edit on `/etc` ? And if I want the new users get the same customized prompt, which file I have to edit?
My doubt is because there is a `profile`, a `profile.d` and a `bash.bashrc` files in `/etc` folder. All of them with bash scripting that I don't kown which lines to uncomment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the system's bashrc by exporting **$PS1** so a user could override a prompt.

Use either scp or clusterssh to distribute it, and if you set up a rsa key you don't even need to enter your password more than once for scp:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
for h in `cat ~/hostlist`; do
    scp ~/newbashrc ${h}:/etc/bashrc
done
eval `ssh-agent -k`
```

Thanks to https://serverfault.com/questions/218629/most-effective-way-to-change-linux-command-prompt-for-all-users for the solution.